# react-modal scroll top when open

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, scrollbar, react-modal

I use `react-modal` to create a open modal form (similar create post modal form facebook).

**My expect:**

When modal is open: scrollbar of window still show but thumb disabled (user can't scroll)

When modal is close: scrollbar of window show and thumb show.

**My problem:**

When modal is open, scrollbar always on top (top = 0). I know because my css `body { position: fixed }` but I want modal look like my expect

Here is my codesandbox for my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-modal-form-rw2sf

Sorry about my bad english and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I set the style of class ReactModalPortal and adjust the z-index. In addition remove the style of body. There is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-modal-form-sfzhr?file=/src/App.js)

```
/* index.css */
.ReactModalPortal {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```
// App.js
...
const portal = document.querySelector(".ReactModalPortal");
portal.style.zIndex = 0;
...
const portal = document.querySelector(".ReactModalPortal");
portal.style.zIndex = -1;
```

Maybe it is not as your expectation, but you could modify it.